# How to create an optionally available stylesheet for visually impared users?

Tags: css, accessibility

I have a WP website that I would like to make easily accessible for visually impaired users. I don't want to modify the default stylesheet, nor I would like to use any plugins, so I am looking for a solution with button or link that would turn on/off a specially designed stylesheet.

My questions... Is it possible to create an alternative stylesheet for a WP site that can be turned on by user request at all?
What do you think is the best way to implement it?

Comment: How is it a wordpress specific question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Easy to setup a button trigger/toggle with a bit of jQuery. Here's a working example I made for you:
https://jsfiddle.net/8Le2tjvr/1/

The Code:

**HTML:**

```
<button id="impaired-button">Impaired Button</button>
```

**jQuery**

```
$('#impaired-button').click(function() {
    $('body').toggleClass('impaired');
});
```

**CSS**

```
.impaired h1 {
    font-size: 50px; 
}
```

Just add .impaired before any css that you want specifically styled for impaired users. This will be shown when the button is clicked.